# Compile Error in Haskell with recursive `let` function with `if then else`

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functional-programming

UPD: Figured it out, I had to type `ghci` first in the terminal

[image]

Hello,

Why does this code:

`let fact n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact(n - 1)`

compile and run in this program in the image, but when I try to do the same, it says

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
main.hs:2:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Has this syntax become outdated?

NOTE: I am using [online gdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_haskell_compiler) because I can't figure out how to install Haskell yet.

Comment: This is not a complete Haskell program. You do not want to compile it. You want to type it in a REPL (GHCi) and play with it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I tried using REPL as you suggested:  https://replit.com/languages/haskell but the code still doesn't work :(

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Okay, I figured it out, I have to type `ghci` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> compile and run in this program in the image, but when I try to do the same.

Because if you write a `let`, it expects an `in …` clause next. In a program, you define functions. You can use the `main` function that will run by default, so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let fact n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1)
    print (fact 5)
```